# What determines the distance between two structure members?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include‬ <stdio.h>
struct test
{
    unsigned int x;
    long int y;
    unsigned int z;
};

int main()
{
    struct test t;
    unsigned int *ptr1 = &t.x;
    unsigned int *ptr2 = &t.z;
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

This program's output is `4` on my system, why do I get this result instead of `2`?
Is the `ptr2 - ptr1` statement correct as `ptr1` and `ptr2` come from pointers to members of the same structure item?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The answer is 42 (as always).

Comment: @Olaf; There are "some reasons" that this code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Answer is 4 not 42

Comment: @ShikharsaranSrivastava; It is also possible that you can see a mammoth on your output terminal.

Comment: @haccks: That's probably because the question has been found, too :-)

Comment: @ShikharsaranSrivastava: You might want to search. The answer is always 42.

Comment: @ShikharsaranSrivastava it's the answer to the universal question of life, the universe and why PHP exists at all.

Comment: Then again maybe the compiler has put ptr2 to the next long boundary so the answer is 8

Comment: Joking apart, where did you get this 'code' from?

Comment: When I run it, I get `4` as an answer.

Comment: strange as I get 2.  My compiler must see this a pointer math and it's two sizeof(ptrs) away x, and y

Comment: @ShikharsaranSrivastava: This could have been an interesting question if you had shown an effort at understanding the program itself, and asking specifically about the part that you didn't understand.

Comment: The answer is 4 because there are 16 bytes difference due to field alignment, and as unsigned are 4 bytes you get 16 / 4 = 4. With a packed structure you should get 3.

Comment: @cleblanc I guess you are as me using windows and the OP must be using any linux. [LP64 and LLP64 are not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: Those who are confused with different outputs should know that C standard strictly says about pointer subtraction: *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
or one past the last element of the array object*. If that's not the case then behavior is undefined. Read para **§6.5.6/8-9**.

Comment: @jdarthenay: That is not universally correct.

Comment: @Olaf What? I mean I said at least three different things, which one is wrong?

Comment: @jdarthenay: Hmm, if you stated three different things, you should make up your mind first anyway;-) But I meant the comment with "The answer is 4 because ...". It can be very different. `int` is not required to be 32 bits. And most architectures available actually have 16 bit `int`s, some 64 bits.

Comment: @Olaf Oh yes, but as you can see I realized it when I understood cleblanc's answer... whatever, as you said sooner this is not supposed to work at all.

Comment: @haccks: While the implementation had problems, there are valid ways to express the same intentions (e.g., using `offsetof()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this outputs `4` has to do with the size of each type and struct padding and alignment.

On my system, `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4, `sizeof(long int)` is 8, and `sizeof(struct test)` is 24.  So to ensure that the 64-bit field lies on a 64-bit boundary, the structure is physically laid out like this:

```
struct test
{
    unsigned int x;     // 4 bytes
                        // 4 bytes padding
    long int y;         // 8 bytes
    unsigned int z;     // 4 bytes
                        // 4 bytes padding
};
```

So when you take the difference between the offset of `x` and the offset of `z`, there are 16 bytes difference.  And since we're doing pointer subtraction, the value of the difference is {byte offset difference} / {element size}.  So we have 16 (byte difference) / 4 (sizeof(unsigned int)) == 4.

If `sizeof(long int)` was 4, then the struct would probably be laid out like this:

```
struct test
{
    unsigned int x;     // 4 bytes
    long int y;         // 4 bytes
    unsigned int z;     // 4 bytes
};
```

In which case the output would be 2.

Note that while the ordering of struct members is defined to be sequential, the layout of the padding is is implementation defined.  Compilers are free to pad as they see fit.

From section 6.7.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> *13* Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the  units  in  which  bit-fields reside **have addresses that
>   increase in the order in which they are declared**.  A pointer to a
>   structure  object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial 
>   member  (or  if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit 
>   in  which  it  resides),  and  vice  versa.   **There may  be  unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.**
>
> ...
>
> *15*  **There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.**